# socket.BeginReceive() renders printer unresponsive

Tags: c#, sockets, printing

I've been developing an application that automatically prints PDF files on specific network printers upon arrival and monitoring `@PJL USTATUS JOB` messages. However, whenever I begin my application and the code hits `socket.BeginReceive()`, the printer is unable to receive any print jobs from any workstation which also means that the callback will never be called. However, if I close my application or just the socket, the printer begins working again.

Am I missing anything? Like blocking/non-blocking or synchronous or asynchronous sockets?

```
public class SocketData {
    public Socket socket;
    public byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[1024];
}

public void Start() {
    // start the thread that checks the printer status
    thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ConnectAndListen));
    thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
    thread.Start();

    // start the file listener
    listener = new FileSystemWatcher(this.WatchPath);
    listener.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(listener_Created);
    listener.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

public void ConnectAndListen() {
        ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(Dns.GetHostEntry(this.IPAddress).AddressList[0], 9100);
        socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        socket.Connect(ipEndPoint);

        //socket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\x1B%-12345X@PJL USTATUS DEVICE = ON\r\n\x1B%-12345X\r\n"));
        //socket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\x1B%-12345X@PJL USTATUS JOB = ON\r\n\x1B%-12345X\r\n"));
        socket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\x1B%-12345X@PJL USTATUS PAGE = ON\r\n\x1B%-12345X\r\n"));
        //socket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\x1B%-12345X@PJL USTATUS TIMED = 0\r\n\x1B%-12345X\r\n"));

        ListenForPrinterReadBack(socket);
}

public void ListenForPrinterReadBack(Socket socket) {
    if (DataRecievedCallBack == null) {
        DataRecievedCallBack = new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived);
    }

    SocketData socketData = new SocketData();
    socketData.socket = socket;

    m_asynResult = socket.BeginReceive(socketData.dataBuffer, 0, socketData.dataBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, DataRecievedCallBack, socketData);
}

public void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn) {
    SocketData socketData = (SocketData)asyn.AsyncState;

    int result = socketData.socket.EndReceive(asyn);

    char[] chars = new char[result + 1];
    Decoder d = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder(); //creating object for decoding
    int charLen = d.GetChars(socketData.dataBuffer, 0, result, chars, 0);
    String recievedData = new String(chars);

    this.Status = recievedData;

    ListenForPrinterReadBack(socketData.socket);
}
```

I know I could do polling, but i won't be able to receive unsolicited printer messages.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**
I'm getting the feeling that only one socket connection is allowed on the printers. Since `socket.BeginReceive()` can only work if the socket is connected, then any other requests cannot be sent since the socket is already being used. Maybe there's another way to handle unsolicited printer readbacks?

Comment: Your problem is elsewere, since `BeginReceive` cannot affect how the other end receives information. show us more code.

Comment: There, I updated the post with more code containing the socket-relevant methods. Thanks for responding, by the way. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do `Send` report that all bytes have been sent (check it's return value)? I can't spot any errors that would prevent the other end from receiving your message. Are you 100% sure that the string you are sending is correct?

Comment: When I send a **@PJL INFO STATUS** a **socket.Receive()** returns data. However, if I choose to use **socket.BeginReceive()**, the printer just stops taking any further commands or print jobs. I'm really baffled myself.

Comment: Have you tried to combine `@PJL INFO STATUS` with `socket.BeginReceive()`?

Comment: I haven't tried that yet, since `@PJL INFO STATUS` returns data instantly. I'll give it a try and keep you posted. Thanks!

Comment: Tried my app with `@PJL INFO STATUS` with `socket.BeginReceive()`, printer still can't accept print jobs while the socket is open. :(

Comment: Yes, it did send back the data related to the query:

`@PJL INFO STATUS
 CODE=100001
 DISPLAY=READY
 ONLINE=TRUE`

I can send more queries to the open socket and receive the printer's response, but I, and everybody else connected to the network, can't send a print job from a different application.

Unless of course I use the socket to send PCL or PS data, then I'll be able to print data. But still, the printer would remain unresponsive to other users.

Comment: Well. The problem is not with the socket since it works with STATUS requests. It's how you sends your job requests that is the problem. Create a new question for that.

Comment: How to create printer jobs using a socket connection? :) Or have I misunderstood what's not working?

Comment: Well, I already know how to send printer jobs using a socket connection. The problem is that when the socket is open, any other application on my workstation or anybody else on the network can't send the printer job to the printer. :) Hope that made sense.

Comment: ok. yes. well. you can't keep the connection open then. Or create a proxy which all other applications must connect through (not an easy task).

Comment: I'll probably just resort to polling then. Thanks for all your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found same problem as yours when using printer

Firstly : Be sure the printer is on "Bi-Directional" mode and try this code:

```
  private void SendCommand(byte[] data, string ip, int port)
    {
        var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        socket.NoDelay = true;

        var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

        socket.Connect(remoteEP);
        socket.Send(data);
        socket.Close();
    }
```

and it will work good.

Best Regards